# Division by zero in Haskell

Tags: math, haskell, division, divide-by-zero

I found a quite strange inconsistency between the behaviour of `div` and `/`.

```
*ghci> :t 1 `div` 0
1 `div` 0 :: Integral a => a
*ghci> :t 1 / 0
1 / 0 :: Fractional a => a
*ghci> 1 / 0
Infinity
*ghci> 1 `div` 0
*** Exception: divide by zero
```

I was quite surprised to notice that the fractional division by zero leads to `Infinity`, whereas `div` correctly leads to an exception.
A `NaN` could be acceptable too for `/`, but why `Infinity`? There is no mathematical justification for such a result. Do you know the reason for this, please?

Comment: Mathematically, having the result of `1 / 0` be `Infinity` is completely justified. It is not the only justifiable return value, but the one that makes the most sense. Note that you will also get a `divide by zero` error if you evaluate `1 / 0 :: Rational`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I wouldn't call it "mathematically completely justified", as this kind of compactification (with positive and negative infinity) destroys quite a lot of theorems which hold on ℝ, and some of those are assumed in many programs.

Comment: You should not assume things like that when working with floating point numbers. Even basic properties like associativity don't necessarily hold. Equality is also not reflexive for `NaN`s! (E.g. `(0/0) /= (0/0)`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout That's why it's not the only justifiable value of `1/0`. But Alexandrov compactification also destroys many useful properties of ℝ - not to mention Čech compactification.

Comment: @DanielFischer: The result would be justified computing it as the limit of 1/x for x->0^+, but not with just a classical simple division.

Comment: So, how do we fix it to give an error for floating point divison by 0, overflow, and other nonsense such as 0 ** 0 ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The reason that `div` does not return `Infinity` is simple--there is no representation for infinity in the `Integer` type.

`/` returns `Infinity` because it follows the IEEE 754 standard (which describes floating point number representations) since the default `Fractional` type is `Double`. Other languages with floating point numbers (e.g. JavaScript) also exhibit this behavior.

To make mathematicians cringe even more, you get a different result if you divide by *negative* 0, despite the fact that `-0 == 0` for floats:

```
Prelude> 1/(-0)
-Infinity
```

This is also behavior from the standard.

If you use a different fractional type like `Rational`, you will get the behavior you expect:

```
Prelude> 1 / (0 :: Rational)
*** Exception: Ratio.%: zero denominator
```

Coincidentally, if you're wondering about why `Integer` and `Double` are the types in question when your actual operation does not reference them, take a look at how Haskell handles defaulting types (especially numeric types) in the [report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4).

The short version is that if you have an ambiguous type from the `Num` class, Haskell will first try `Integer` and then `Double` for that type. You can change this with a `default (Type1, Type2...)` statement or turn it off with a `default ()` statement at the module level.

Comment: Where can I learn about the `default` statement? I haven't seen it before.

Comment: The section of the report I linked to covers it near the end. I think it's also mentioned in the Gentle Introduction to Haskell. However, I am not sure there is much more to it than I covered here. (Unless you enable some extensions, it only concerns the numeric types and behaves like I explained.)

Comment: I just entered it into GHCi. Which version of GHC do you have? Also, what happens if you just try `1/0`?

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: Thanks for your answer, it is quite complete indeed. I have a last doubt: the IEEE standard you mentioned doesn't seem to be the best way to deal with divisions by zero, it kinda assumes them as limits for the denominator that goes to 0 instead of real divisions. Shouldn't be better to just throw an exception, just like  `div` does?

Comment: @Riccardo Haskell doesn't specify what should happen when you divide by 0 with floating point numbers. Typically, it will just do a floating point division, so what happens depends on the mode the FPU is in.  This is just like C.

Answer (score 6):

I hope this helps:

```
Prelude> 1/0
Infinity
Prelude> -1/0
-Infinity
Prelude> 0/0
NaN
```

Comment: Thanks... yes it just looks like a limit put that way.

Answer (score 5):

It may not be that way for a mathematical reason. `Infinity` is used sometimes as a "sin bin": everything that doesn't work in our system cleanly, put it in there.

Example:

```
Prelude> 10 ** 10 ** 10
Infinity
```

... is definitely not mathematically justified!

Comment: You haven't met a hard core finitist yet! :)

Comment: @Ingo Hard core as in zero, one, infinity?

Comment: @Daniel I mean the people who are maintaining that a number like 10^100 makes no sense as there are not as many objects in the universe. But perhaps they would prefer 10^10^10 = NaN

Comment: @Ingo You can always ask for the number of combinations of objects in the universe and suddenly a lot more numbers are useful for you since you must use the factorial:)

Comment: @Piotr - I think it is better to reject their arguments on other grounds. While (10^100)! might indeed be huge, it's still finite, and thus they feel justified in their silliness.

Answer (score 3):

Fractional is *not* equal to Float (or Double) type.

Fraction of 1/n where n goes to 0 so lim(n→0) 1/n = +∞, lim(n→0) -1/n = -∞ and that makes sense.

Comment: I think a `Fractional` constraint gets defaulted to `Double`, which is a floating point type. Read the section of the report I linked to.

Comment: Correct, @TikhonJelvis, unless there is a default declaration saying otherwise, an ambiguous type with a `Fractional` constraint is defaulted to `Double`.